# Why did Hashem create the world in such a way that a leap year is needed?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, calendar, astronomy, adar, avodath-hashem

I understand why we have a leap year; to keep the sun and moon cycles in sync, so that Pessach is always in the spring.

That's all technical, as a result of the moon orbiting *too slowly* - or the sun *too fast*.

**On a philosophical / theological level, why did Hashem create the world in such a way that a leap year is needed?**

**What does Hashem *expect to achieve* (or rather *expect us to achieve/accomplish*) with this extra month?**

Surely there's some aspect of Avodat Hashem that depends (or can be improved) by understanding the point of the The Leap Year concept.

Comment: Why did Hashem create the world requiring some months to have 29 days and some months to have 30 days?

Comment: @C.BenYosef - kind of a related question, on a smaller scale, but more frequent.

Comment: yagdil torah...

Comment: Interesting Q. But I think there is a given premise as to why the Judaic year is based on the moon rather than the sun. One reason I heard is that just as the moon waxes and wanes, so too do the Jewish people - they lose strength and regain it. Also, the moon reflects the light from the sun like Jews reflect the light of Torah from G-d. Based on this premise, and the need to coordinate our calendar with solar b/c of Pesach, thus the need for leap years.

Comment: @DanF - you don't think it's possible to create a model that the moon cycles are an exact fraction of the sun's cycle? IOW the  lunar cycle could have been 30.4.. days long instead of 29.5... days long.

Comment: Just as the famous constant *pi* can be approximated by 22/7, so can Euler's number *e* be estimated at about 19/7. Now, there are 7 leap years to a [Metonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle) 19-year cycle, and the strictly-solar year consists of 12 + 7/19 lunar months, whereas the strictly-lunar year amounts to a total of 354 + 7/19 days. Also, 19 + 7 = 26, the value of the Tetragram, representing the only number squeezed between a square (25) and a cube (27), thus reminding us of the Creator's uniqueness. Modern *string theory* ascribes 26 dimensions to the physical world.

Comment: @Lucian - that's fascinating (though I didn't check the facts), but only reinforces the question of why it couldn't be a "normal" number or fraction. Why the rounding?

Comment: @DannySchoemann: I don't know why, but, as a person born on the nineteenth day of the seventh month (September) of the solar year, I'm glad He didn't.

Comment: I would title "leap month (Adar Bet) is needed" instead of "leap year".

Comment: I recall that there are 12 permutations of G-d's name (3 letters X 4 places) which create names for the 12 months (as said in Musaf Rosh Chodesh). The 13th month that is beyond that (and beyond the 12 constellations) should represent something similar to Kutzo Shel Yod - something beyond the physical reality, maybe "out of this world" experience. Maybe Zohar has some special Kavvonos on Adar Bet?

Comment: This is a great question on the imperfection of our world, which seems to contradict G-d's wisdom. There is no correlation between all planets and luminaries and turned out (pretty recently) nothing is constant at all. You might expand your question into the total lack of correlation between the solar bodies including Earth's rotation.

Comment: @DannySchoemann *"you don't think it's possible to create a model"* - that is exactly what I would expect from G-d's wisdom. Exactly 28 days (4 weeks) month, exactly 336 days year to show G-d's glory. Now that everything is a mess and we wonder how come?

Answer (score 9):

To solar cycle represents continuity and consistency. The lunar cycle represents rise and fall, [והחיות רצוא ושוב](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16099#showrashi=true&v=14).

The two cycles don't inherently mesh, and it takes the actions of people (as represented by Beis Din which sets the leap year) to combine the two.

See [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1208/jewish/The-Nineteen-Year-Marriage.htm) for a similar expression of this idea.

In terms of lessons in Avodas Hashem, there are many. But one obvious one is that in Torah you have the idea of Chiddush (innovation) - כל מה שתלמיד ותיק עתיד לחדש נתנה למשה מסיני - Whatever a zealous student will innovate was given to Moshe at Sinai (Yerushalmi Peah Chapter 2). Questions, answers and uncertainty on the one hand, but with the solid basis of Torah MiSinai on the other.

It takes zealous learning (Beis Din) to create a chiddush in harmony with Torah Misinai, and not מגלה פנים בתורה שלא כהלכה - propounding ideas as Torah which contradict Halacha.

Comment: Thanks, @Yishai, but I am still left with my questions - why is the leap year needed, and what does Hashem expect to achieve (or rather expect us to achieve/accomplish) with this extra month?

Comment: @DannySchoemann, Um, the answer certainly attempts to address those questions. Perhaps you can elaborate on how you feel they remain unanswered?

Comment: you are doing a great job explaining the lunar cycle and its lessons. But you are not explaining what "the extra Adar" is supposed to teach us. (Assumption: It can't just be an "accident" of the disjoint between the solar and lunar calendars.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann, you mean an extra month generally, or a second Adar specifically?

Comment: Reb @Yishai, as a first stab, I'd like to understand why there's an extra month every so often (7/19 years) - what does Hashem want/expect us to do with this extra month? As a bonus we can discuss why it's Adar in particular.

Comment: I was also a bit disappointed by this answer. 1. Humans have no inherent need in matching years and months, no need in counting months altogether. We do it because of Torah commandment. So the OP asked why and you answered because we need to match. 2. The second part is motivational propaganda and has nothing to do with the Q - this can be said just about anything.

Answer (score 5):

A different angle on the question: at the funeral for Rabbi Emanuel Gettinger (who was a mathematics and astronomy enthusiast), [it was suggested](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcktnzRP-1Y#t=56m) that God values our engaging the world. This way, we would have to study astronomy to determine how to modify the calendar.

(Recall that the Gemara praises the role of an honest human judge as "partnering with God.")

Answer (score 3):

It does have the effect of making Adar longer with its increased happiness.
(This is an incomplete answer, but I can not just add a comment)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this article](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lbwXSrbe2xXyo-QRZAKiahrqGDmN-OYzqR-OYbPXldE/edit?usp=sharing) the ideal Jewish year is actually 13 months (representing a dominance of the Jewish lunar calendar over the non-Jewish solar one) and it will resume this cycle in the days of Moshiach. The leap month is added to provide access to the future redemption even in our times.

Comment: For the record: (Anonymous) article  claims it's an idea from the מהרש"א in Sanhedrin 12a